# Преобразование div в изображение и его печать

Tags: javascript, canvas

Хочу распечатать содержимое div со стилями и т.п. Решил преобразовать содержимое в картинку, а после распечатать. Для преобразования воспользовался библиотекой [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). После этого попытался создать новое окно, поместить туда изображение и вызвать печать.

```
printTable() {
    let printContents = document.getElementById('results_table');
    html2canvas(printContents).then(function(canvas) {
        let win = window.open();
        win.document.write("<br><img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"'/>");
        win.print();
    });
}
```

При вызове функции открывается новое окно и диалог печати, но в предварительном просмотре отображается пустая чистая страница.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же закрыть диалог печати, то на самой странице изображение будет присутствовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если после этого нажать ctrl+P, то откроется диалог печати, где в предварительном просмотре будет фото и его можно будет без проблем распечатать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так? И как можно при вызове функции реализовать задуманное - преобразование содержимого div в изображение и его печать?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что данные добавлялись дольше, чем открывался диалог печати. Сделал функцию асинхронной

```
printTable() {
    let printContents = document.getElementById('results_table');
    html2canvas(printContents).then(async function(canvas) {
        let win = window.open();
        await win.document.write("<br><img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"'/>");
        win.print();
    });
}
```